# matplotlib polar plot set_ylabel on the left hand side

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, polar-coordinates

I want to write the ylabel on the left hand side in polar plot as that in the non-polar plot. Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
axes=matplotlib.pyplot.figure().add_subplot(1,1,1,polar=True,frameon=False)
import numpy
x=numpy.linspace(0,12*numpy.pi,2000)
axes.plot(x,numpy.exp(numpy.cos(x))-2*numpy.cos(4*x)+numpy.sin(x/12)**5,color="black")
axes.set_xlabel("y")
axes.set_ylabel("$P_y$")
axes.set_xticklabels([])
axes.set_yticklabels([])
axes.grid(False)
import matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf
output=matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages("butterfly.pdf")
output.savefig()
output.close()
```

And I get the result like this:
[image]

However, I do not like the P_y at the middle of picture, I want it go back to the left hand side, just like this:

[image]

I just want to change ylabel to the left hand side, other detail about the difference of such two picture can be ignore. I try to use:

```
axes.set_ylabel("$P_y$",position=(0,0.5),transform=axes.transAxes)
```

But do not help.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It is controlled by `axes.yaxis.labelpad` property in a polar plot. You can set it to positive number to mover the label to the left, say 120

[image]