# matplotlib polar plot set label position

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to reposition the y or "r" label on a polar plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi)
r = np.linspace(0, 2)
plt.polar(theta, r)
rlab = plt.ylabel("Directivity [dB]")
rlab.set_position((1.0, 0.6))
rlab.set_rotation(0)
plt.show()
```

which gives:

[image: /Users/Atom/figure_1.png]

and seems to ignore the x position argument. I would like the label to appear just outside the plot, to the upper right of the yticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position is changing, the command isn't being ignored. You can check it by playing with the value of `x` in `rlab.set_position((1.0, x))`.

That being said, I am not finding any effect of the first argument in the position tuple. What's more surprising is that the first value is being reset:

```
>>> rlab.get_position()
(372.8395415374975, 0.6)
>>> %hist -op 57-62
>>> rlab.set_position((5.0, 0.9))
>>> rlab.get_position()
(5.0, 0.9)
>>> plt.show()
>>> rlab.get_position()
(372.8395415374975, 0.9)
```

So while the vertical position is being changed, the horizontal one isn't. Seems like either a bug or a deliberate intent of the developers.

As a work-around, you could work with positioning a text label:

```
ax = plt.gca()
plt.text(1, .8, "test", transform=ax.transAxes)
```

Alternatively, you could add padding to the ylabel, like this:

```
ax.yaxis.labelpad = -100 # negative padding pushes the label to the right
```

(which was a suggestion found [elsewhere on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23416773/2476444)), but I find this method less flexible.

Comment: By x position  argument, I meant the horizontal component of the tuple - sorry I should have been more clear.